# Connecting to mongodb

Tags: node.js

Code:

```
     var Db = require('mongodb').Db,
        Server = require('mongodb').Server,
        Client = new Db('test', new Server('127.0.0.1', 52235, {}))
```

In Function:
         ...

```
     Client.open(function(err, pClient) {
        Client.collection('test_insert', function(err, collection){
            collection.find().toArray(function(err, results) {
                console.log(results);
            });
        });
        // etc.
     });
```

This shows error: Cannot read property 'arbiterOnly' of undefined
can you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs because it couldn't connect to the server and so the configuration information wasn't properly received. Probably you are using the wrong port: try 27017.

Comment: yes, you are right. I've allready changed port number and it's connecting successfully. but now i have following problem: in mongodb console i wrote: use test_insert and then db.test_insert.insert({id:"3"}). this created collection named test_insert right? but when I wrote console.log(results) it returns "[]". i'm new in mongo and node. please help me

Comment: Client = new Db('test', new Server('127.0.0.1', 52235, {}))